# How do I delete images of some versions on carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I use carrierwave.
Recently I figured out how to recreate other visions using recreate_versions!
something like this

```
Model.all.each do |model|
    model.image.recreate_versions!
end
```

But I realized this method just creates new versions, it does not delete previous version's images.

Is there method that deletes images that version do not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Internally CarrierWave uses a method `remove_versions!` but it's private.
But it's easy to reimplement:

```
Model.all.each do |model|
  model.image.versions.each { |name, v| v.remove! }
end
```

if you wish, you can filter your versions by name (symbols).

There is no way to delete files that have no (longer) a releated version unless you use the file system directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks for that:

I guess the mounted object is Image. so you can do the following:

```
after_update :remove_prev_version

def remove_prev_version
  @model.remove_image
end
```

Please note that you need to do it on the `before` and not `after` as you want old image to be deleted.